# How to replace all, and then add a numbering sequence marking replacements?

Tags: php, replace, seo, numbers, sequence

Hello I have the instance of the filename: losangeles.php 2252 times and I want to change it to losangeles-0001.php, losangeles-0002.php, losangeles-0003.php so on and so on, up till losangeles-2252.php, How is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: how did u created multiple files in same filename in a dir ?

Comment: what do you mean by *instance of the filename*?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [preg_replace_callback function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like in this code:

```
$str = <<< EOF
losangeles.php
losangeles.php
losangeles.php
EOF;
$str = preg_replace_callback('#\b(losangeles)(?=\.)#i',
          create_function('$m',
                          'static $i=1; return $m[1] . sprintf("-%04d", $i++);'),
          $str);
echo $str . "\n";
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
losangeles-0001.php
losangeles-0002.php
losangeles-0003.php
```

#### Live Demo: http://codepad.org/aMB9CMTZ

Comment: sorry to confuse everyone with the php extension. I have a file that called losangeles.php OR losangeles.html which has a table of data. The table has 2252 rows. On each row, is a link with losangeles in the path. I am using Text Wrangler to replace-all with losangeles-0001. Then I would like to replace the next one with losangeles-0002. How can I just replace all of them at once with a numbered sequence automatically added on the end of "losangeles"

Comment: Can you paste a small subset of your html file in your question.